# Why am I getting error calculating postfix last operator?

Tags: java, stack

The project is asking to use Stack to calculate a postfix expression, this one in particular:

5.0 3.5 - 1.2 /

Now my code works fine for this postfix expression:

2 3 +

What am I missing that is giving me the following error?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty
>   String
>       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
>     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)   at
>   java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)     at
>   java.lang.Double.(Double.java:608)  at
>   project.Calculator.processIn(Calculator.java:55)  at
>   project.Project_main.main(Project_main.java:25) Java Result: 1

```
package project;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;



public class Calculator {
    Stack<Double> calcStack = new Stack<>();
    ArrayList<String> operators = new ArrayList<>();

    public Calculator() {
        operators.add("+");
        operators.add("-");
        operators.add("/");
        operators.add("*");
    }

    public double processIn(String expression){
        String[] express = expression.split("");

        String temp = "";
        for(String j : express){
            if(operators.contains(j)){
                System.out.println("Operator Reached: " + j);
                double operand2 = calcStack.pop();
                double operand1 = calcStack.pop();

                double tmp = 0.0;
                if(j.compareTo("*") == 0){
                    tmp = operand1 * operand2;
                    System.out.println("Performing multiplication on " + operand1 + " and " + operand2);
                    calcStack.push(tmp);
                }
                else if(j.compareTo("/") == 0){
                    tmp = operand1 / operand2;
                    System.out.println("Performing division on " + operand1 + " and " + operand2);
                    calcStack.push(tmp);
                }
                else if(j.compareTo("-") == 0){
                    tmp = operand1 - operand2;
                    System.out.println("Performing subtraction on " + operand1 + " and " + operand2);
                    calcStack.push(tmp);
                }
                else if(j.compareTo("+") == 0){
                    tmp = operand1 + operand2;
                    System.out.println("Performing addition on " + operand1 + " and " + operand2);
                    calcStack.push(tmp);
                }
                System.out.println("Pushing result to stack: " + tmp);

            }
            else if(j.compareTo(" ") == 0){
                double newOperand = new Double(temp);
                temp = "";
                System.out.println("Pushing to stack: " + newOperand);
                calcStack.push(newOperand);
            }
            else{
                temp = temp + j;
                System.out.println("Current temp value: " + temp);
            }
        }
        return calcStack.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is line 55 in your class?

Comment: double newOperand = new Double(temp);

Comment: It does this when it it hits a " "(a space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this will solve your problem.
split with " "(space) instead of ""

```
String[] express = expression.split(" ");
```

and change your else to bellow

```
else {
    double newOperand = new Double(j);
    System.out.println("Pushing to stack: " + newOperand);
    calcStack.push(newOperand);
}
```

and remove else if bellow

```
else if(j.compareTo(" ") == 0){
    double newOperand = new Double(temp);
    temp = "";
    System.out.println("Pushing to stack: " + newOperand);
    calcStack.push(newOperand);
}
```

this way you directly add numbers to your stack.
your error was happening because of how you handle space after operations. when you have numbers followed by numbers else gets called first and then if for space. so you temp value has a number in it. but after finishing an operation you reach a space gain right away but you have no value in your temp so new Double(temp) throws an exception since temp is not a number.
so another way to fix your code if you want to keep it as it is, is to use try and catch like below.

```
else if(j.compareTo(" ") == 0){
    try{
    double newOperand = new Double(temp);
    temp = "";
    System.out.println("Pushing to stack: " + newOperand);
    calcStack.push(newOperand);
    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
        //skip
    }
}
```

this way you catch your error without breaking your code. but i recommend the first solution.

Comment: But how will it know when to end a number? For example 5.0?

Comment: well you have a space between each number and operation so when you split with space all parts are complete. you will have an array of ["5.0", "3.5", "-", "1.2", "/"]

Answer (score 0):

Please split the string on space " " as Shawn suggested like `expression.split(" ")` *(but this assumes that your expression would always contains spaces between operator and operands)*. This would give you two types of tokens/strings operands and operators. Here is more simplified implementation of your code. Please notice the `expression.trim()` operation to avoid any trailing spaces.

[BTW, I have tried in eclipse and it works :) ]

```
public double processIn(String expression)
{
    expression = expression.trim();
    System.out.println("Trimmed expressoin : " + expression);
    String[] express = expression.split(" ");

    for(String j : express){

        if(operators.contains(j)){
            System.out.println("Operator Reached: " + j);
            double operand2 = calcStack.pop();
            double operand1 = calcStack.pop();

            double tmp = 0.0;
            if(j.compareTo("*") == 0){
                tmp = operand1 * operand2;
                System.out.println("Performing multiplication on " + operand1 + " and " + operand2);
                calcStack.push(tmp);
            }
            else if(j.compareTo("/") == 0){
                tmp = operand1 / operand2;
                System.out.println("Performing division on " + operand1 + " and " + operand2);
                calcStack.push(tmp);
            }
            else if(j.compareTo("-") == 0){
                tmp = operand1 - operand2;
                System.out.println("Performing subtraction on " + operand1 + " and " + operand2);
                calcStack.push(tmp);
            }
            else if(j.compareTo("+") == 0){
                tmp = operand1 + operand2;
                System.out.println("Performing addition on " + operand1 + " and " + operand2);
                calcStack.push(tmp);
            }
            System.out.println("Pushing result to stack: " + tmp);

        }
        else {

            double newOperand = new Double(j);
            System.out.println("Pushing operand to stack: " + newOperand);
            calcStack.push(newOperand);
        }
    }
    return calcStack.pop();
}
```